# Running a jar file in run.batch in windows i am getting could not find or load the main class

Tags: java

@Title FSS - MFMSr %Date% %Time%

@set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin";

@echo "%LOCALCLASSPATH%"

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\apache-activemq-4.1.1.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-beanutils.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-collections.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-dbutils-1.1.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-lang-2.2.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\commons-pool-1.3.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\cryptix32.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\quartz-all-1.6.6.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\ojdbc6.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\mail.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\disruptor-3.4.2.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\log4j-core-2.13.3.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\httpcore-4.0.1.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\json-simple-1.1.1.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%LOCALCLASSPATH%;.\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.28.jar

@set LOCALCLASSPATH=%CLASSDIR%;%LOCALCLASSPATH%;
@echo "%CLASSDIR%";

:x

@echo "%LOCALCLASSPATH%";

@java -classpath AEPS_IPPB_2.0.10.jar ;%LOCALCLASSPATH% com.fss.m24.FIMSMessage24 start 60000 -Xincgc -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -Xincgc -XSS:1024M

@echo Start Time %Date% %Time% >> RestartLog.txt

@goto x

@cd..
pause

Comment: ""
"";
";;.\lib\apache-activemq-4.1.1.jar;.\lib\commons-beanutils.jar;.\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;.\lib\commons-collections.jar;.\lib\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar;.\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;.\lib\commons-dbutils-1.1.jar;.\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;.\lib\commons-lang-2.2.jar;.\lib\commons-pool-1.3.jar;.\lib\cryptix32.jar;.\lib\quartz-all-1.6.6.jar;.\lib\ojdbc6.jar;.\lib\mail.jar;.\lib\disruptor-3.4.2.jar;.\lib\log4j-api-2.13.3.jar;.\lib\log4j-core-2.13.3.jar;.\lib\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;.\lib\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;.\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar;.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;.\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.28.jar;

Comment: and also hetting this error "Error: Could not find or load main class " but i have added path every thing but still getting this error

Comment: Please help me to get out of this

Comment: i want to run a jar file in run.batch through run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

the space between

```
@java -classpath AEPS_IPPB_2.0.10.jar
```

and

```
;%LOCALCLASSPATH%
```

seems wrong.